# Using Content.Load<> in a class/subclass

Tags: c#, class, load, xna

I'm wondering if there is anyway to use the "Content.Load<>" in a class that is not the game itself, say I want to load a texture from within the class, rather than sending the texture to it.

```
namespace ProjectGame1
{
    public class Ship
    {
        public Texture2D texture;

        public Ship()
        {
        this.texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
        }
    }
}
```

That's an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to pass your ContentManager to the Ship object:

```
public Ship(ContentManager content)
{
   this.texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");
}
```

From your game class you instantiate the Ship:

```
Ship ship = new Ship(this.Content);
```

Comment: @JoDG the problem here is that I can't send the default Content to the new Ship when I try ti instantiate it outside of the game default  LoadContent()

Comment: While this will work, it's probably better (from a conceptualization standpoint) to make "Ship" a subclass of "DrawableGameComponent", as stated in some of the other answers.

Comment: when I type in "Content" or "this.Content" on the instantiate it is no where to be found, it doesn't show up in the (help list, if that's what you call it).

Comment: @user669415 It's called "IntelliSense"

Comment: @user669415 where are you trying to call the  `new Ship(this.Content);` from?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I recommend ***not* using DrawableGameComponent**, my reasoning for this is [outlined in this answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-are-the-cons-of-using-drawablegamecomponent-for-every-instance-of-a-game-obj/9209#9209).

Now, to make your code work as-is, you need to pass a `ContentManager` into the constructor you are creating (see [JoDG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392876/using-content-load-in-a-class-subclass/5392995#5392995)). But to do this you must only construct it after the `ContentManager` is ready. For `Game`'s content manager, this is during and after `LoadContent` being called (so not in your game's contstructor or `Initialize` method).

Now, you could do something *like* using DrawableGameComponent, which is much nicer: Just give your `Ship` class a `LoadContent` method, and call that from your game's `LoadContent` (as you would do for `Draw` and `Update`).

If the texture that your ship uses is not part of your ship's state (ie: all ships use the same texture), you could even make it static, saving you from having to call `LoadContent` on every ship you create. I have an example of this is [this answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/when-should-a-bullet-texture-be-loaded-in-xna/9310#9310), which also has a list of other useful information about Content Manager.

Comment: How do you change the `DrawOrder` if you aren't using the `DrawableGameComponent`?

Comment: @Neil You call the functions directly. So `player.Draw(); enemy.Draw();` becomes `enemy.Draw(); player.Draw();`. Simple.

Answer (score 3):

If the class derive form `DrawableGameComponent` then you still can use
`Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");`

Comment: how would I make it derive from the DrawableGameComponent?

Comment: just make it: "public class Ship : DrawableGameComponent"

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work, you'll need a `Constructor` that accepts a parameter of type `Game`.  This will mean you'll need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game`.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace ProjectGame1 
{     
    public class Ship : DrawableGameComponent // Notice the class now inherits from
    {                                         // DrawableGameComponent
        public Texture2D texture;          

        public Ship(Game game)         
            : base(game) // <<---- Don't forget to pass Game to the base constructor
        {         
            this.texture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship");         
        }     
    } 
}
```

Comment: this worked for a single class, however my "Ship" is a parent class of the class "Enemy" (it contains the basics such as texture, position etc) When I use the Enemy subclass of Ship, is there something I must pass on since Visual C# doesn't really say anything, it just errors out.

Comment: Note that, in order to have the LoadContent() override called, the Ship object must be added to Game.Components (i.e., in the Ship constructor, "Game.Components.Add(this);").

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a reference to the Game object to get its `Content` member.  This could either be passed in or you could make the game a Singleton.

Comment: Yes I could pass it, new problem though is when I'm trying to pass it to a sub-class outside of the "protected override void LoadContent()" it can not be found and I've tried making the LoadContent a public but that doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it, I used a different method since yours didnt quite work as I'd expect.
What I did was make a "public static ContentManager asd;" and then assigned it to Game's ContentManager, and then it worked by redirecting it to "Game1.asd
(Variable names are examples)