# How to change DrawOrder without using DrawableGameComponent

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Reading another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392876/using-content-load-in-a-class-subclass) it seems that `DrawableGameComponent`s aren't the way forward.  I took this upon myself to do a bit of research and using the [Particle sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/particle_3d) from the [XNA Creators website](http://create.msdn.com), I decided to strip out the use of `DrawableGameComponent`s.  Everything compiled fine, except for the fact that I don't have `DrawOrder` available and the example uses this for the particles.

How can I change the `DrawOrder` as if I was using a `DrawableGameComponent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GameComponent`s are a great tool, and can make your code much easier to use and reuse. I would disregard Andrew Russell's answer from the other SO question. It is highly biased. `GameComponent`s are fine to use. They are similar to a Singleton. You wouldn't abstain from using the Singleton pattern because somebody expressed a negative opinion for it, would you?

Trying to duplicate this functionality that already exists in the framework is just silly. Andrew Russell's opinion was that `GameComponent`s can make your code messier. I would argue that trying to write your own layered drawing system would make your code messier.

*Bottom line*: Use the functionality that already exists. Don't change your coding style because somebody insulted it. You don't have to use the latest and greatest when the older style still works.

Comment: *Technically* my answer is "opinionated" (an informed opinion, no less), not "biased". If you need a game-global, data-driven, component-based system for your game - then obviously use `GameComponent`s - don't duplicate the functionality. However, like the Singleton pattern, that architecture is not ideal *most* of the time, [as I describe in this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-are-the-cons-of-using-drawablegamecomponent-for-every-instance-of-a-game-obj/9209#9209). Just because the API exists does not mean it is the only way or the best way to structure your game.

Answer (score 3):

I won't tell you which approach is better, but this is how you would do it without using GameComponents:

In the game's Draw method, you call the Draw methods of the particle systems in the order you want:

```
smokePlumeParticles.Draw(gameTime);
explosionSmokeParticles.Draw(gameTime);
projectileTrailParticles.Draw(gameTime);
explosionParticles.Draw(gameTime);
fireParticles.Draw(gameTime);
```

Comment: The first draw calls will be the first items drawn. @JoDG: Was it your intention for the smoke to be in the background, behind all other items drawn?

Comment: That was the idea indeed, based on the original code: `// Set the draw order so the explosions and fire
            // will appear over the top of the smoke.
   smokePlumeParticles.DrawOrder = 100;
   explosionSmokeParticles.DrawOrder = 200;
   projectileTrailParticles.DrawOrder = 300;
   explosionParticles.DrawOrder = 400;
   fireParticles.DrawOrder = 500;`